# DataGrid resize on browser resize (not really working)?

Tags: gwt

dataGrid (GWT 2.5) doesn't resize on browser window resize. The layout is DockLayoutPanel center -> DockLayoutPanel center -> dataGrid, the page's DOCTYPE ist 'standard'.
When the page gets rendered and I resize the browser, the height of the grid isn't adjusted accordingly. I have to click into the grid to have it resized.
Any help welcome

TIA gve

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. It wont be easy for anybody to help without seeing code snippets. Please take time to provide more details in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using RequireResize panels in all layout hierarchy. ie

> use only Layout panels staring from RootLayOutPanel

.